# How to stop a stream computing in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I created some stream table in TDengine. How can I stop some of those tables? If I stop those tables, can I restart them?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below sql to stop a stream

```sql
taos> show streams;
       streamId       |           user           |           dest table           |        ip:port         |      created time       |        exec time        |       time(us)        |              sql               |   cycles    |
=======================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 9:1                  | _root                    | query_res                      | 192.168.1.98:35806     | 2021-12-24 16:45:28.287 | 2021-12-24 16:43:30.000 |                     0 | select count(*)    from stb... |           0 |
Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.004967s)

taos> kill stream 9:1;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.000837s)

taos> show streams;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.003737s)
```